# burninate [font-matching]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burnination

Should we remove the [font-matching](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-matching) tag?

There are 3 questions using [font-matching](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-matching) that also have [font-recommendation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-recommendation).

I see that the later is already used in more questions, and seems redundant to have both (questions about font matching are a sub-type of font recommendation).

I can just go on and edit the questions to remove the tags if it's alright.

Comment: Seems like a good plan to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This just looks to me like a synonym of [font-pairing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-pairing). We can go ahead and create the link if there's no objection.

Comment: maybe we can just replace it with font-pairing? Do we really need both? They're not that insanely popular anyway.

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Comment: @Luciano that's essentially what making a tag synonym does